# Problemas com Thread em JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

Estou criando uma aplicação para receber as portas seriais em uso do computador usando a biblioteca [jSerialComm](http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/).

Para isso, gostaria de ficar atualizando essa informação em um `ComboBox`. Porém não consigo implementar a *Thread* corretamente.

Utilizei o `Service` e o `Task`. Mas sem sucesso.

Segue o código:

```
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    private static ComboBox<String> cbPortas = new ComboBox<String>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();

        Label lblPort = new Label("Selecione a porta:");
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(lblPort, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(lblPort, 50.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(lblPort, 95.0);

        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(cbPortas, 40.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(cbPortas, 65.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(cbPortas, 65.0);

        Button btnConectar = new Button();
        btnConectar.setText("Conectar");
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(btnConectar, 100.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(btnConectar, 50.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(btnConectar, 50.0);

        Button btnIniciar = new Button();
        btnIniciar.setText("Iniciar Controle");
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(btnIniciar, 150.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(btnIniciar, 50.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(btnIniciar, 50.0);

        root.getChildren().addAll(lblPort,cbPortas,btnConectar,btnIniciar);     

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,320,220);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<Void> createTask() {
                return new Task<Void>() {           
                    @Override
                    protected Void call() throws Exception {
                        //Background work                       
                        SerialPort[] portNames = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
                        for(SerialPort portName:portNames){
                            cbPortas.getItems().add(portName.getSystemPortName());
                        }

                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        service.start();

        launch(args);

    }
}
```

Como proceder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o problema está na alteração dos itens do combobox que você está fazendo, vamos tentar usar um `ObservableList`.

Atributos:

```
private ObservableList<String> items;
private Service<Void> service;
```

Método start:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // [...] Código omitido
    items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    cbPortas = new ComboBox<String>(items);

    service = new Service<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask() {
            return new Task<Void>() {           
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    //Background work
                    items.clear();                       
                    SerialPort[] portNames = SerialPort.getCommPorts();

                    for(SerialPort portName:portNames){
                        items.add(portName.getSystemPortName());
                    }

                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    };
    service.start();

    root.getChildren().addAll(lblPort,cbPortas,btnConectar,btnIniciar);     

    Scene scene = new Scene(root,320,220);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

O método main fica somente com o `launch(args)`, ele é mantido por motivos de compatibilidade, tudo fica no método start. Esse service também só será executado uma vez, se sua intenção for executar periodicamente pode tentar o [ScheduledService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html).